# PHP foreach loop, unique <select> id for getElementById

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, getelementbyid, unique-id

What I am interested in getting is $option_value['price'] in a string from the dropdown, not . Using .value returns the later.

I have select menus that are created in a foreach() loop. The drop downs will hold price options. I am trying to give each product it's own id so I can use the javascript onChange() function to update prices on the screen.

The select tag looks like this:

```
 <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" class="select_options" id="select_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" onchange="getIt(this);">
```

and the javascript:

```
function getIt(el) {
var id = el.id;
a = document.getElementById(id).text;
alert(a);   
}
```

Alerting out id gives me select_some number. So I can see that it is getting the id. but alerting out a gives me [object HTMLSelectElement].

so I tried

```
alert(a.options.selectedIndex.value);
```

and get unidentified.

```
<?php if ($product['options']) { ?>
<div class="options" id="option_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
<?php foreach ($product['options'] as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
<div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option select_option">    
  <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" class="select_options" id="select_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" onchange="getIt(this);">

    <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>

    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
    (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><span id="newPrice"><?php echo str_replace('.00','.',$option_value['price']); ?></span>)
    <?php } ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Show us the generated HTML code

Comment: so is there a way I can get the text shown on the drop down ($xx.xx), instead of the value that the option is 0,1,2,3,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"is there a way I can get the text shown on the drop down ($xx.xx), instead of the value?"*

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function getIt(el) {
   var a = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
   alert(a);
}
```

`el.selectedIndex` gives you, obviously, the index of the currently selected option, which you can use as an index into the collection of options, `el.options`, and then get that option's `text`. The `text` property belongs to each option, not to the select.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FCnUQ/

(Note that if no option is selected `selectedIndex` will be `-1`.)

You don't need to use `getElementById()` at all because you already have a reference to the element, `el`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after... It's tough asking the question correctly since I'm crap at coding.

Answer (score 3):

Change :

```
  a = document.getElementById(id).text;
```

To:

```
  a = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

That will alert the value of selected option.

Comment: that shows the value of the option... 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. I am interested in the price:  $xx.xx. I thought getElementById().text gave what was shown in the dropdown...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, put `document.getElementById(id).value` instead of `document.getElementById(id).text`

```
function getIt(id) {
 a = document.getElementById(id).value;
 alert(a);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you passing this like `getit(this)` you should code like this

```
function getIt(el) {
var id = el.id;
a = document.getElementById(id).value;
alert(el.value);   //you can directly alert like this
}
```